# I need some guidance with javascript Object

Tags: javascript, object

My issue is the following. I have the following object:

```
let obj =  {
id: 1404,
fecha: 2018-03-18T06:47:28.365Z,
tabla: 'usuarios',
operacion: 'UPDATE',
usuario: 'user',
valor_nuevo:
 { nombres: 'John',
   apellidos: 'smith',
   direccion: 'some cool place' },
valor_anterior:
 { nombres: 'name',
   apellidos: 'last',
   direccion: 'addres' } 
}
```

I need to basically take the nested objects `valor_nuevo` and `valor_anterior`, extract each element, copy the unnested elements and assign them to a new object with the extracted elements in the nested object. Something like this:

```
obj =  {
 {
  id: 1404,
  fecha: 2018-03-18T06:47:28.365Z,
  tabla: 'usuarios',
  operacion: 'UPDATE',
  usuario: 'user',
  valor_nuevo: 'John',
  valor_anterior: 'name',

 },
 {
  id: 1404,
  fecha: 2018-03-18T06:47:28.365Z,
  tabla: 'usuarios',
  operacion: 'UPDATE',
  usuario: 'user',
  valor_nuevo: 'smith',
  valor_anterior: 'last',

 },
 {
  id: 1404,
  fecha: 2018-03-18T06:47:28.365Z,
  tabla: 'usuarios',
  operacion: 'UPDATE',
  usuario: 'user',
  valor_nuevo: 'some cool place',
  valor_anterior: 'address',

 },
}
```

How can I achieve this result?

Comment: Please visit the [help] to see what and [ask]. HINT: Post effort and CODE. But first do a minimum of research. There are hundreds of object manipulation examples. Search for json map for example

Comment: Please show what you try!, i think it is simple task

Comment: Your expected output seems invalid JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to do it. It assumes that `valor_nuevo` and `valor_anterior` have the same number of keys with matching values:

```
let obj = {
    id: 1404,
    fecha: '2018-03-18 T06:47:28.365 Z',
    tabla: 'usuarios',
    operacion: 'UPDATE',
    usuario: 'user',
    valor_nuevo: {
        nombres: 'John',
        apellidos: 'smith',
        direccion: 'some cool place'
    },
    valor_anterior: {
        nombres: 'name',
        apellidos: 'last',
        direccion: 'addres'
    }
};

var base = Object.assign({}, obj),
    nuevo = base.valor_nuevo,
    anterior = base.valor_anterior,
    ret = [];

delete base.valor_nuevo;
delete base.valor_anterior;

for (key in nuevo) {
    ret.push(Object.assign({
        valor_nuevo: nuevo[key],
        valor_anterior: anterior[key]
    }, base));
}

console.log(ret);
```